# Regular Expressions in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I'm having trouble with regular expression, that works fine on RegExr.com and JS Console. But fails on Google Apps Script.

**regex.gs**

```
function parse()
{
  var regExp = /mobileheading=\"End\sDate\"\>[^\<]+\<\/div\>/

  var html = get_html();  
  Logger.log(html.match(regExp));

}
```

RegExr link - http://regexr.com/3fcsg

The link above, has the the sample text obtained from `get_html()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex looks good. Remember to add the "g" flag to the regex to capture all matches. It might be an issue with the get_html() method itself.

```
function parse() {
  var regExp = /mobileheading=\"End\sDate\"\>[^\<]+\<\/div\>/g
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page.html").getContent();
  Logger.log(html.match(regExp));  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit! You were right, the issue was with `get_html()`.

I was under the impression, the regex wasn't working. But reading output from html file was a nice tip!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the [*global*](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp) flag. So, the following code should work :

```
function parse() {
    var regExp = /mobileheading=\"End\sDate\"\>[^\<]+\<\/div\>/g;
    var html = get_html();
    Logger.log(html.match(regExp));
}
```